# Should the user be allowed to favorite their own question?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Favorite, like up-vote, is a currency of sorts. I say this since there are badges based on the number of favorites you get off of your question.

So, why is it that a user is allowed to favorite their own question?

The only reason I can think of is: You have asked quite a lot of questions and need to 'bookmark' a few for later use.

Answer (score 2):

Well the only badges for favorite questions required 25 and 100 favorites, so it's pretty minor gaming at that; at best you get a 4% head start by favoriting your questions. Those badges are *very* rare by the way.

It seems to be more of an issue of "why not", allowing favoriting does allow users to bookmark questions keeps the interface a bit simpler as it's one more feature that just always works with no special conditions. In reality "favorites" are more accurately "bookmarks" for most practical purposes. Favorited questions don't get extra prominence anywhere so there's really not much to gain by randomly favoriting everything you've done.

Comment: That would lead to the questioning of the badges then. If the purpose of the favorite is bookmarking, then why give out badge for it too. Since, if you look at the functionality, you cannot see how many people have favorited your questions, only which questions you have favorite (bookmarks).

Comment: My bad, you can see the number of favorites on your questions' page.